# How can I filter URL in htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

How to redirect urls like

```
www.domain.com/pageX?yyyy
```

To

```
www.domain.com/pageX
```

in htaccess.

So far I'm checking if the query string contains '?' but don't know how to take only the first part of the query string.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  this to discard query string from your URLs

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule (.+) /$1? [L,R=301]
```

If you are on Apache 2.4 then you can  use QSD flag instead of using "?" to trim the query string.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)$
RewriteRule (.+) /$1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```